# How to get the statistics info for one interface through linux command?

Tags: linux, tcp, statistics

we know that some linux command can get tcp statistics info ,such as "netstat -s --tcp" ,"ss -s -t" , but how to get statistics for one specific interface ?

Comment: I need to get the tcp statistics with specific interface since the interface up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`tcpstat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tcpstat) :

> tcpstat - report network interface statistics

`tcpstat -i <interface>`

If you want to launch it when interface is up, you can use `post-up` in `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto enp4s0f1
iface enp4s0f1 inet dhcp
post-up /etc/init.d/tcpstat start enp4s0f1
```

`/etc/init.d/tcpstat` is an `init.d` script, I have created containing :

```
#!/bin/bash
#title         :tcpstat
#description   :start/stop/restart tcpstat
#########################################
### install   :  cp tcpstat /etc/init.d/
#                update-rc.d tcpstat defaults
### uninstall :  update-rc.d -f tcpstat remove

usage(){
    echo "Usage: service tcpstat {start|stop|restart} <interface>"
}

DEFAULT_LOCATION="/tmp/dump"
EXEC="/bin/tcpstat_run"

if [ ! -z "$2" ]; then

    if [ ! -z "$3" ]; then
        STORAGE_FILE="$3"
    else
        STORAGE_FILE="${DEFAULT_LOCATION}_$2"
    fi

    if [ -f $PID_FILE ]; then
        echo "file exist"
    fi

    case "$1" in
        start)
            echo "Starting tcpstat service on inteface $2..."

            daemonize -E INTERFACE=$2 -E DUMP_FILE=$STORAGE_FILE $EXEC

            echo -e "\E[31;33m[ OK ]\E[0m"
            ;;
        stop)
            echo "Stopping tcpstat service..."

            pkill -f "tcpstat -i $2"

            echo -e "\E[31;33m[ OK ]\E[0m"
            ;;
        restart|reload)
            "$0" stop "$2"
            "$0" start "$2"
            ;;
        *)
            usage
            exit 1
    esac
else
    usage
fi

exit $?
```

Note that I have used `daemonize` instead of `start-stop-dameon` for RHEL compatibility.

`daemonize` launch the following exec located in `/bin/tcpstat_run` :

```
#!/bin/bash

tcpstat -i "$INTERFACE" > "$DUMP_FILE"&
```

You can modify these script to your liking especially if you want to save dump at a specific location & invoke special treatment in `post-down`.

For instance, if you try this as is, you will get following output :

```
user@user:~$ tail -f /tmp/dump_enp4s0f1 
Time:1468847225 n=9 avg=66.56   stddev=35.76    bps=958.40
Time:1468847230 n=9 avg=87.33   stddev=40.17    bps=1257.60
Time:1468847235 n=14    avg=130.50  stddev=66.08    bps=2923.20
Time:1468847240 n=3 avg=46.00   stddev=0.00 bps=220.80
Time:1468847245 n=12    avg=58.50   stddev=11.26    bps=1123.20
Time:1468847250 n=9 avg=115.78  stddev=78.32    bps=1667.20
Time:1468847255 n=169   avg=135.22  stddev=188.26   bps=36564.80
```

Comment: Is this command is a "standard" command that contained by most main Linux distributions ?

Comment: no its not installed by default on Linux distros but available on most package manager

Comment: The "tcpstat -i <interface>" can do a live capture with specific interface, but how to get the statistics data since the  interface up?

Comment: Which Linux distrib are you using ?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2

Comment: I have updated my post with `post-up` script with an `init.d` script which should work on RHEL